# Word choice- Curtailed, reduced, cutback.. etc

Tags: word-choice, expressions

Need a word that would fit in the place of the bold word.

Over the years, however, the program has considerably **curtailed** its commitment of safeguarding the unemployed.

Background: The program/policy has intentionally reduced benefits for workers, and it also has increased eligibility requirements over the years. Hence, workers find it increasingly difficult to access the program/benefits.

Saying that the program has performed poorly or has failed does not capture the right meaning. The program has not failed, it is efficient and works well. Just that it does not want to cover as many workers as before. When it was established, the program was very generous and its purpose was to cover all unemployed workers.

I am open to restructuring the sentence. But cannot use the words benefits/coverage/access/eligibility, I want it to be something related to safeguarding the unemployed.

Thanks!

Edit: Is renege the correct word?

Comment: Note that it would not be "cutback".  The program has *cut back* it's commitment.  "Cutback" is a noun, not a verb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To rephrase the sentence (as you had suggested):

> Over the years, however, the program has ***revoked*** *many* safeguards for the unemployed.

[**Revoke**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/revoked):

> to annul by recalling or taking back : rescind · *revoke* a will
>   to bring or call back
>
> The judge *revoked* her driver's license.
>   Their work permits were *revoked*.
>   Their privileges were *revoked* after they misbehaved.

---

There is nothing to prevent you from combining a couple of words suggested here—depending on what you're actually looking for. (In part of your question you imply actions, in another part you imply intentions.)

> Over the years, however, the company has **reneged** on its commitment to the unemployed and **revoked** many of their safeguards.

Comment: Jason, while renege does mean to go back on one's commitment/promise, I am not sure if it captures the scenario appropriately. Like, the program does not say they wont help the unemployed anymore, its just that they have built this incredibly complex criteria that people need to fulfill. These restrictions were not there before. It is a way for the program to discourage workers from qualifying for benefits.

Answer (score 1):

**Renege** fits well in your question. [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/renege)

> 1. To fail to carry out a promise or commitment

As in:

> Over the years, however, the company has reneged on its commitment to
>   the program safeguarding the unemployed.

Comment: +1 I think your answer made sense too, in the right context. :)